# Polite ARIA live region for a game with high rate of messages

Tags: html, macos, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm running a little game on the web. In order for it to be optimally screen reader accessible, incoming messages, which can be about in-game actions or user text chat, have to be read automatically as soon as they arrive.

Reading of messages has to be quick, but also reliable. Messages have to be read in order, and none must be prematurely interrupted or completely skipped.
Otherwise, players may miss important events or information.
Sometimes, messages arrive with a quite high frequency and/or in a burst. In any case, they have all to be read in order and without interruption.

It may happen that the user can't catch up because messages arrive too fast. In this case, he/she usually press the shut up key, often the Ctrl key. This has normally for effect to stop speaking immediately and drop all queued messages.
The screen reader itself isn't supposed to determine without user intervention if a message can safely be dropped. Some screen readers give a second option to skip the current message and go directly to the next, for example Shift with NVDA. These shortcuts are well known by all screen reader users.

Unfortunately, all that is only theory, and in practice, I have trouble finding a way which works well everywhere.

The most problematic case is VoiceOver on the Mac, which seem to always whether interrupt the message currently being spoken as soon as a new one arrive (as if the region was assertive instead of polite, what isn't desired), or decide to skip messages randomly.

I have currently 7 demo pages where I experiment different ways of using polite ARIA live regions, and this has been tested by me and my tiny team with as most combinations of browsers, devices and screen readers as we can.
Below you will find my findings so far.

Can you suggest something that works everywhere ?
Can you, in particular, find a working solution for VoiceOver on Mac, which seems to be the most problematic ?

Of course if there is no universally working solution, it's always possible to make user agent detection, but it would be preferable to avoid it.

As a reminder, this is for a game, so requirements are high: messages must be read in order, without interruption (unless the user requires it), and without skips, even when messages arrive quickly in bursts. Since we don't want any interruption, assertive instead of polite isn't a solution.

#### Progress so far

Here are the different techniques tried so far:

1. [Single zone, appending p](http://vrac.quentinc.net/aria-live-test-1.html)
2. [Single zone, appending span](http://vrac.quentinc.net/aria-live-test-2.html)
3. [Single zone, appending div](http://vrac.quentinc.net/aria-live-test-3.html)
4. [Single zone, using insertAdjacentHTML](http://vrac.quentinc.net/aria-live-test-4.html)
5. [Single zone, replace using innerHTML](http://vrac.quentinc.net/aria-live-test-5.html)
6. [New live region for each message](http://vrac.quentinc.net/aria-live-test-6.html)
7. [Roundrobin 10](http://vrac.quentinc.net/aria-live-test-7.html)
8. [Single zone with role=log](http://vrac.quentinc.net/aria-live-test-8.html)

And here are the current results:

| Combos/pages | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chrome + Jaws | OK | repeat | OK | repeat | skip | no read | disorder | OK |
| Firefox + Jaws | Ok | Ok | OK | Ok | OK | OK | OK | OK |
| Edge + Jaws | OK | repeat | OK | repeat | skip | no read | disorder | OK |
| Chrome + NVDA | OK | no read | OK | no read | no read | no read | disorder | OK |
| Firefox + NVDA | OK | no read | OK | no read | no read | no read | OK | OK |
| Edge + NVDA | OK | no read | OK | no read | no read | no read | OK | OK |
| Safari iOS | Ok | OK | OK | OK | OK | OK | OK | OK |
| Firefox iOS | Ok | OK | OK | OK | OK | OK | OK | OK |
| Chrome iOS | Ok | OK | OK | OK | OK | OK | OK | OK |
| Safari Mac | Interrupt | Interrupt | Interrupt | Interrupt | Interrupt | Skip | Skip | interrupt |
| Chrome Mac | Interrupt | Interrupt | Interrupt | Interrupt | Interrupt | Skip | Skip | interrupt |
| Firefox Mac | Interrupt | Interrupt | Interrupt | Interrupt | Interrupt | Skip | Skip | interrupt |
| Chrome Android | Ok | Repeat | Ok | Repeat | Skip | Ok | Ok | OK |
| Firefox Android | repeat | repeat | repeat | repeat | OK | no read | no read | repeat |

All tests have been made with the most up to date versions of OS, browsers and screen readers at the time of this post, 4th of  may 2022.

- **OK** means that everything is fine, i.e. messages are read in order, aren't interrupted, skipped over or uselessly repeated.
- **no read** means that nothing is read at all
- **interrupt** means that messages currently being read are interrupted when new messages arrive, all or most of the time, or at random
- **skip** means that messages are reandomly skipped over
- **repeat** means that several messages are repeated twice or more, or that the entire zone is read again from the beginning each time a new message arrive
- **disorder** means that messages aren't read in order / the order don't seem deterministic. This especially happens when the rate is quite high (less than 100ms)

#### Conclusions so far

The behavior of live regions works globally well (except on mac) for simple things: a serie of paragraphs or divs containing simple text. It's encouraging.
However, as soon as the content become a little more complex, behaviors quickly start to be erratic. You need to be very careful about what you put in the live region, and how do you put it.

As a consequence of previous point, you have probably whether to simplify the output a lot, or separate ARIA live region zone from the content actualy displayed on screen. This is a little sad to maintain duplicates, but not grave either. Do you think it's a good option to separate ARIA live output and display in two distinct zones, if you can't simplify enough to have a stable behavior ?

You must be very carful when using multiple polite ARIA live regions, because in general they won't be read in a consistent order.

IN the opposite of many beliefs, and probably against the specification, ARIA live regions created on the fly aren't universally read if they contain text at the time of their addition to the DOM.
This is especially the case with Chrome and Edge under windows with both Jaws and NVDA.

As I'm initially asking, VoiceOver does a poor job on Mac, and nothing works well !
Is that a bug of the Mac ? It's especially both sad and surprising that, in the opposite, Apple seem to make a perfect on iOS.
If this is indeed a bug of VO Mac, is it relevant to send a report to Apple at accessibility@apple.com ? Or is there another mean ?

Thank you very much for all your answers or general ideas.

Comment: Have you tried `role="log"`?  Instead of having a bunch of live regions, perhaps have a visually hidden log region where all the text you want announced is sent to it.  In theory it's just a polite live region but perhaps some OS's interpret the role with more semantics.

Comment: @slugolicious: No, as I have always thought that it was exactly synonyms, but good idea. I'll try it and report how it does.

Comment: It might analogous to role=alert. While that gives you an assertive region, it also has special meaning to the OS and you often hear “alert”.  Perhaps the OS does something special with “log”. Probably not likely but worth checking.

Comment: I have added a test #8 with a role=log as suggested. Unfortunately, it doesn't change anything, the result is the same as with page #1. Question is updated with a new 8th column.

Comment: Have you tried using `aria-atomic` and / or `aria-busy` along with `aria-live`? I also remember (though i don't remember *why*) in some cases for MacOS VoiceOver it needed the `aria-live` attribute to be toggled off and then back on.

Comment: aria-busy and aria-atomic don't do anything useful. They make the whole text to be repeated again. At which moment exactly am I supposed to remove aria-live attribute and put it back?

Comment: @QuentinC have you found a solution for the VoiceOver issue?

Comment: Yes and no. I propose an option to activate window.speechSynthesis instead of ARIA-live. It seems to be much more reliable on the mac, but it isn't ideal for several other reasons (double speech, need to reconfigure speech settings, need for a non-standard shut up key, and more simply need to activate that mode). I'm not satisfied of that solution and find it extremely sad that no true solution with ARIA live exists.