# How can I prevent the screen reader from stopping to read the content when the focus is gained to the input field from an aria-live region div?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs3, accessibility, nvda

I have a chatbot interface where a live region div with an aria-live attribute is used to display new messages. The live region updates correctly and the screen reader starts to read the content, but it stops reading in the middle when the focus is gained to the input field. This is causing confusion for screen reader users and makes it difficult for them to understand the new messages.

I am looking for a solution to ensure that the screen reader continues to read the new messages until they are finished and that the focus management is correct when the live region updates. Is there any solution to ensure that the live region updates are announced by the screen reader in a timely manner and the focus is managed correctly?

**Screen Reader:** NVDA + Firefox

Comment: Are you saying that you're moving the focus in the middle of the live region being read?  If so, it's the screen reading software's decision on whether the text will be interrupted and the new text (newly focused element) is read. That's how a screen reader works. If you navigate to some text (whether via the TAB key or a screen reader navigation key), the text of the element will be read. If the text is long and you navigate again while the screen reader is still reading, most screen readers will stop reading the text then start reading the new text. Are you using `polite` or `assertive`?

Comment: Are you saying you're moving the focus to the middle of the live region being read?
While a set of bot responses are being added, the input box is disabled and after the messages appended to the container, the focus will be gained to the enabled input text box. These messages can be a bit longer texts as well.

 Are you using polite or assertive?
I had tried with both of them & received same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can neither ensure that the screen reader will read new messages entirely, neither be certain that new incoming messages won't interrupt older ones. Be it because of a notification of any kind, because the focus changes, or whatever else.

### Politeness level of aria-live

Remember by the way that [`aria-live=assertive`](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#aria-live) normally means always interrupt what's currently being spoken, so it's rarely a good idea to do so. It's much better to keep `aria-live=polite`.

As [my own observations show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72119260/polite-aria-live-region-for-a-game-with-high-rate-of-messages), you can help a little screen readers to be more stable, avoiding many unwanted interrupts/skips/repeats, though, by being very careful on what you do exactly in the live region.

### Change of focus

However and in particular, live-region messages are interrupted when the focus changes. You can't prevent the screen reader from immediately announcing the focused element when the focus changes.

In principle, this is much more important to have this information in a timely manner, rather than any message coming from a live region. Reactiveness to tab, arrow keys and other important keys is crucial for a good user experience, as well as always exactly knowing where you are and what you can/should do.

So, it's perfectly normal that focus change takes the priority almost above everything and that you can't influence on it.

The best way to avoid focus changes taking the priority over everything else is in fact very simple: **don't move the focus unexpectedly** unless you have a good reason.

In your chatbot example, there is no reason to move the focus upon arrival of a new message. If the focus was in the text box when the user pressed enter to submit a question, the focus should stay there as long as the user don't explicitly leave it by him/herself.

If the focus stays in the text box, then the screen reader user can just have the response automatically read via aria-live, and can directly type in a new message when ready. The conversation can go quick and fluent.

### Avoid DOM changes close to focus

Avoid making changes to the DOM enclosing or nearby the text box. A change in the DOM, especially when using frameworks like angular or react, basically means removing it and adding it again. At worst the focus can be completely lost, at best it still creates a focus jump out and in again that will generate an unwanted interruption.

The best is to test what you can or can't change without triggering a DOM rebuild, and adjust your HTML structure in consequence.

### Leave users in control to read messages

Don’t forget that screen reader user already can quit the textbox and read the missed messages on their own terms. A screen reader already has shortcuts to read backwards (up arrow in NVDA). This will just not work inside the textbox.

Still, it would seem a best practice to allow focussing single chat messages. This is especially true if there are actions you can take on these messages, like replying, editing or deleting.

[Microsoft Teams simply allows for tab navigation between chat messages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-screen-reader-to-chat-in-microsoft-teams-c99901c9-00dc-44d4-8921-4aa120bf298b#bkmk_readchat_win), but it’s a dedicated chat application.

If the conversation is embedded in a larger page, it should be treated as a [composite widget](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#composite), which only has one focus stop, but allows focussing the contained controls via vertical arrow keys:

> Authors SHOULD ensure that a composite widget exists as a single navigation stop within the larger navigation system of the web page. Once the composite widget has focus, authors SHOULD provide a separate navigation mechanism for users to navigate to elements that are descendants or owned children of the composite element.

[Livechat seems to use arrow keys to navigate between messages](https://developers.livechat.com/updates/livechat-accessibility-screen-readers)

Comment: With respect to front-end frameworks/libraries like React/Angular/Vue, in case a re-render is occurring caused by state change that you cannot control, try to time the live announcement after this state updates. As in, instead of having aria-live on chat messages container, have a dedicated sr-only announcement span where you can populate your new in-coming message and clear it soon after. This is other than the existing functionality already in place.

Comment: I’d like to add that it should be easily possible to re-read messages in the conversation. I would suggest arrow keys to focus single messages, since often they offer actions as well. What do you think Quentin?

Comment: @Andy: this is a good idea: the messages could be in a listbox or textbox, but stay careful: tab shouldn't allow to focus every single message but only reach the list or text area only once. For info, discord currently has this problem of tab focusing every single message and it makes navigation very annoying.

Comment: Yes to establish a [composite widget](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#composite) is exactly what I would want to recommend. MS Teams does use Tab too, but it’s a dedicated application, not a chat window. Good to know that you (as a sr user) find that annoying.

Comment: @QuentinC I took the freedom to edit the answer and add that recommendation. Feel free to correct or reject my edit.

Comment: I don't know if comments are the right place to comment edits, but your changes are pretty good, thank you very much. Just a note, the headings should be H3 inside a post and not H2 to correctly follow SO page structure.

Comment: Just to be more precise for my previous comment, I find annoying to have each message individually reachable with tab. It's useless and long. But a composite widget with a single tab stop and up/down to navigate between messages is excellent. Well thought, you might use a div with role application but be careful, you can easily end up completely breaking accessibility with role application.